# Cat B15Q smartphone Bluetooth LE and iBeacons

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am developing an Android application using iBeacons. The iBeacon detection is working for devices from API level 18+, with two different implementations for 18 < API < 20, and API 21+. So far I have tested on different devices, mostly Samsung (S4, S5,...).

While testing using the CAT B15Q (API level 19) rugged android smartphone, I experienced that even the check wether Bluetooth LE is returning true, and the iBeacon bluetooth device is discovered during the bluetooth scan, the bytes received as scanResult do not describe a valid Beacon device. It is definitely a problem with the CAT smartphone, as the implementation for API level 19 is working on a Samsung GT-N5100.

The data is returned as parameter "scanRecord" by the callback

```
public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)
```

An expected result (e.g. on the Samsung GT-N5100) would be like this:

```
212611-176096013-64-88964000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

or

```
21626-1760221-9-126109-9079-9478-104-12836-6891113-32-119623-243-22-77897511111011697107116210-12102213-487611665725055100000000000
```

The CAT B15Q device gives

```
897511111011697107000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

or

```
21000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The described behavior can be observed using estimate and kontakt.io iBeacons.

Has one of you observed a similar behavior on other android devices, or is this a bug in the CAT B15Qs bluetooth device ? Does anyone know a method to make beacon proximity detection work on the the CAT B15Q ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: At the very least, you should post the bytes you *are* receiving in comparison to those you *expect*, and the *return value* of the call you used to receive them.  You might also want to try someone else's off the shelf scanner app - it is entirely possible that the implementation of the API on a particular phone is broken - there have certainly been enough bugs and oddities in BLE on even flagship devices.

Comment: sorry, yes, of course, i added the expected and experienced data, and clarified the questions..